# extracting two random sample sets in python

Tags: python, random

I have generated random nos from 1 to 539 with size being 269.

```
train=randint(1,539,269)
```

now i want to generate test data nos not containing the train data nos

Comment: That is not valid code; `randint` only takes two arguments.

Comment: What is `randint`?  Python's `random.randint` only takes 2 arguments.

Comment: randint(low,high,size) is the syntax

Comment: looks like another XY problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking for half the numbers in that range to be in `train`, the other half in `test`:

```
all = range(1, 539) # numbers from 1 to 538
random.shuffle(all) # shuffle them randomly
test = all[:239] # first half in test 
train = all[239:] # second half in train
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll guess that you really want numbers from 1-538 (because it's divisible by 2), and that your data set doesn't replace numbers after selected.  An easy way to get them is to just generate them all, shuffle, and split the result:

```
n = range(1, 539)
random.shuffle(n)
n1 = n[:len(n)//2]
n2 = n[len(n)//2:]
```

Each is 269 elements long and each number occurs only once between the both of them

```
>>> len(n1)
269
>>> n1[:10]
[188, 295, 213, 372, 150, 535, 16, 363, 137, 285]
>>> n2[:10]
[276, 307, 314, 404, 409, 205, 523, 119, 224, 487]
```

If you're using NumPy, maybe:

```
>>> n1, n2 = np.random.permutation(538).reshape((2, -1)) + 1
>>> n1[:10]
array([ 43, 195, 280, 241, 135, 277, 304, 320,  93,  13])
>>> n2[:10]
array([ 81, 179, 102, 520, 244, 288, 111, 524, 507, 356])
```